# ObjectOutputStream writeObject() method returning empty file

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a save feature that will save the current status of the game. Here is my code:

```
public class MyGame extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Serializable {

     private void saveGame(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               

        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        int user_command = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this);
        if (user_command == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            try {
                File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
                MyGame saveFile = this;

                outputStream.writeObject(saveFile);
                outputStream.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {System.out.println("ioexception");}
        }

    }
```

The resulting saved file is 0 bytes. I tried debugging the program and it crashes on the outputStream.writeObject(saveFile) line. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Its reporting the IOException

```
ioexception
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.paintRegion(SynthLookAndFeel.java:386)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.update(SynthLookAndFeel.java:350)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthRootPaneUI.update(SynthRootPaneUI.java:77)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:752)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5128)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1479)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1410)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1224)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1015)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:21)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:60)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:97)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1780)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3375)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:796)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:713)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:693)
    at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(SystemEventQueueUtilities.java:125)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:641)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:611)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.paintRegion(SynthLookAndFeel.java:386)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.update(SynthLookAndFeel.java:350)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthPanelUI.update(SynthPanelUI.java:94)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:752)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1029)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5124)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1479)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1410)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1224)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5072)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4882)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:785)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:713)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:693)
    at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(SystemEventQueueUtilities.java:125)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:641)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:611)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.paintRegion(SynthLookAndFeel.java:386)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.update(SynthLookAndFeel.java:350)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthPanelUI.update(SynthPanelUI.java:94)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:752)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1029)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5124)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1479)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1410)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1224)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5072)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4882)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:785)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:713)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:693)
    at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(SystemEventQueueUtilities.java:125)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:641)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:611)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.paintRegion(SynthLookAndFeel.java:386)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.update(SynthLookAndFeel.java:350)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthPanelUI.update(SynthPanelUI.java:94)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:752)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1029)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5124)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1479)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1410)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1224)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5072)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4882)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:785)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:713)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:693)
    at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(SystemEventQueueUtilities.java:125)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:641)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:611)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.paintRegion(SynthLookAndFeel.java:386)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.update(SynthLookAndFeel.java:350)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthPanelUI.update(SynthPanelUI.java:94)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:752)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1029)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5124)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1479)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1410)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1224)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5072)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4882)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:785)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:713)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:693)
    at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(SystemEventQueueUtilities.java:125)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:641)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:611)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.paintRegion(SynthLookAndFeel.java:386)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.update(SynthLookAndFeel.java:350)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthPanelUI.update(SynthPanelUI.java:94)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:752)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1029)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5124)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1479)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1410)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1224)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5072)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4882)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:785)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:713)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:693)
    at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(SystemEventQueueUtilities.java:125)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:641)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:611)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.paintRegion(SynthLookAndFeel.java:386)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.update(SynthLookAndFeel.java:350)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthPanelUI.update(SynthPanelUI.java:94)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:752)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1029)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5124)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1479)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1410)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1224)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5072)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4882)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:785)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:713)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:693)
    at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(SystemEventQueueUtilities.java:125)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:641)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:611)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.paintRegion(SynthLookAndFeel.java:386)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.update(SynthLookAndFeel.java:350)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthPanelUI.update(SynthPanelUI.java:94)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:752)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1029)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5124)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1479)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1410)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1224)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5072)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4882)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:785)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:713)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:693)
    at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(SystemEventQueueUtilities.java:125)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:641)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:611)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: Try flushing your output stream before closing it.

Comment: move the close() method to a finally block in the try-catch.  Also, stick some logging messages into the existing catch blocks.  You might be throwing an exception and not reporting it.

Comment: @NathanD.Ryan: unnecessary.  closing an outputstream will always flush it first. the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Are you sure what you are attempting to write to the file?

Comment: @Wug: Ah yes, where is my head at. Probably the first thing to try is to actually report the exceptions, rather than ignore them.

Comment: Also, saving the whole GUI is probably a dumb way to save the state of a game.  Make a GameState class or something that implements Serializable instead and save that.

Comment: @Wug - Excellent idea! OP is serializing the entire `JFrame`. The docs for `JFrame` state: "**Warning:** Serialized objects of this class will not be compatible with future Swing releases."

Comment: Try not ignoring exceptions, too.

Comment: When you catch an exception in `saveGame`, instead of calling `System.out.println("ioexception");`, call `e.printStackTrace();`. That will provide the information needed to make progress on your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Create a GameState class for your game (implementing serializable) and save that instead.  You're getting an exception from trying to serialize the JFrame, and by the looks of that monster, you're not going to be finding a workaround any time soon.

```
// GameState.java
class GameState implements Serializable
{
    public int score;
    public int numFoos;

    // etc etc
}

// MyGame.java
public class MyGame extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
    private GameState myState;

    private void saveGame(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
    {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        int user_command = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this);
        if (user_command == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            try
            {
                File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));

                outputStream.writeObject(myState);
                outputStream.close();

            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {System.out.println("blaaagrgr");}
            catch (IOException e) {System.out.println("ioexception");}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That repeated exception's not from saving the game, it's something completely unrelated. `JFrame`s should be serializable, but you're right in that it's probably not useful in this case.

Comment: mm, you're right.  That would explain why it's a NPE and not an IOE.

Comment: More importantly, the `saveGame()` method isn't in the stacktrace. (NPEs are unchecked so one could still occur there.)

Comment: Wouldn't know. One might argue that you're not really resolving whatever problem the OP has there. (Which is impossible until he gives us the stacktrace for the IOE.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure doing this would solve his problem, if in a roundabout way.

Comment: (By wouldn't know I mean I'm not the downvoter, that was just a guess at the reason.)

Comment: Hi Wug, that question i had ealier which made no sense (String class and stack being 0xD). Turns out it had nothing to do with any of my code nor the String class. It was because the calling C function didnt have the function prototype of the function that called that and did something that broke C<->C++

Comment: So it was because not even your code had prototypes?  I hope you learn something from this.

Comment: @Wug: There were prototypes, there are just two c files and it didnt have a prototype for one function and there were no warnings, error or anything. And no code had to be changed, just a prototype had to be seen which is ridiculously weird especially when there is no implicit conversion. So yeah the printfs did match the code i was running, the results it showed were real. It was just a missing prototype and no warnings

Answer (score 0):

You should log your exceptions instead of silently ignoring them. My guess is that you have some field in `MyGame` that either isn't `Serializable` or itself contains something that isn't fully serializable.

You probably shouldn't be serializing the entire `JFrame`, though. It's not a good way to save your game because the serialization won't be compatible with future releases of Swing.

Comment: Exception in edited answer is an NPE which isn't caught, so effectively logged. That was overlooked, so it would seem that merely logging exceptions is not an effective way to deal with them. - Edit: There is an IOException there, as well as NPEs elsewhere.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline - It's too bad OP hasn't posted the IOException. It's doubtful that the exceptions that have been posted are the source of the problem: the stack traces show no trace of OP's code. These NPEs could not have come from the thread that was executing the code that was posted.

Comment: It *should* have come from the same thread. The stack traces are from the EDT thread and the code is using Swing. Assuming this is true, the NPEs come after `saveGame` has exited.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline - Oh, I just noticed that OP decided to report an IOException by printing the word "ioexception". Brilliant. It does look like the stack trace is from after `saveGame` returns.